# Rejected git push

Tags: git, github, push

```
To git@github.com:xxx/xxxxx.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:xxx/xxxxx.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes before pushing again.  See the 'Note about
fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

I got this error when I tried to push some changes. When I try to fetch from repo i get

```
From github.com:xxx/xxxxx
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
```

What should I do to solve this ? It's been basically just me on the repo so far, I've had just two pushes from someone else. Do I need to do a proper merge ?

Comment: Did you read the note about fast-forwards in the help, as the error message stated?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The push is failing because your refs are behind those of the remote repository.  The fetch operation only brings down the contents and refs of the remote repository but does not update your refs to the changes.  Hence it does nothing to resolve the problem preventing the push.  You'll need to either do a pull operation or manual merge with the local version of the remote refs.

Comment: Yep, I solved it just before reading your response. The pull solved it, but I'll mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: `git pull` does a `git fetch` followed by a `git merge`

Comment: you can also do git rebase origin/master and then git merge origin/master to keep the history linear and not too messy.