# Push committed files to GitHub

Tags: github, push, commit

I have repository in GitHub. I edited files in my PC, committed them and now I want to push these files to GitHub. How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the files are already cloned from a github repository `git push` will do it.

```
cd /path/to/repo
git push
```

If this local repo does not belong to any github repo, create a repository in github. This will give you a git repo url like `git://github.com/username/project.git`. Now you need to add this url as remote to your existing local repository

```
cd /path/to/repo
git remote add origin git://github.com/username/project.git
```

Then you can commit your changes and push it

```
git push
```

Comment: I wrote git push, but there is an error: ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:ziyaddin/git-loader.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: Issue a git pull first. It'll merge the repo then you can continue as usual. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713137/github-first-push-problem-how-to-merge-remote-changes and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945080/rejected-git-push

Comment: thanks a lot! I used git add <file> to remove error, and then I tried git push and it done. :) Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Go to github and create a repository under your account (if you haven't already). If you've done that, follow the instructions for pushing code from an already existing repository.

Comment: yes, I already have a repository. What command I must use to push changes to GitHub?